# Getting all hashtags from a user

Tags: java, rest, instagram, instagram-api

I need some pointers in how to achieve the following results:

- Get user IDs of people that have a certain hashtag used, i.e. get all users ( or at least a 1000) that have #snowy used. The way I was thinking of doing this is to get a random 1000 photos with #snowy and extract userID from the JSON? I am aware of the 20 response objects limit.
- Afterwards, I would like to get all the hashtags used by a given userID. I would like to get a set of hashtags used per userID in a following manner:

  ```
  {userID},{#snow,#sunny#life, and the rest of hashtags associated with that userID}
  ```

Currently, I do not see how can I POST userID and get all the hashtags user has, is it even possible or can someone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [`/tags/tag-name/media/recent`](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) API endpoint and providing a count parameter you can receive more than 20 photos doing the pagination.

There are no API endpoints to get all the tags for a specified user. You may query all the media posted by that user ([`/users/user-id/media/recent`](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent)) and extract the used hashtags.